# Java NIO closing one channel resulting the other channel not responding

Tags: java, sockets, concurrency, network-programming, nio

I just found that the problem might due to multi-threading problem. After the read() method I sent the request to several worker threads to process the data. When the thread pool size is 1, the problem doesn't occur. However, when the thread pool size is bigger than 1, this problem occurs.

I initialized my threadpool before the while(true) loop, and execute my worker thread after the read() method.

I'm using Java NIO in a middleware that connects a memtier client and a memcached server. The system works fine with only one clients connected, however, when there are more clients connected, when one client finishes and closes its channel, the other client won't be able to read or write to its channel any more.

My implementation looks like the following:

```
public void run() {
    try{
         // Connect to client
         selector = Selector.open();
         ServerSocketChannel server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
         server.configureBlocking(false);

         InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(8000);
         server.socket().bind(address);
         server.register(selector,SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

         // Connect to Server
         Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",8090);

         // Select keys
         while (true) {
             selector.select();
             Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

               while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                     SelectionKey key = iterator.next();
                     iterator.remove();

                     // check if key is valid
                     if(!key.isValid()) {
                           continue;
                     }

                     if(key.isAcceptable()) {
                         accept(key);
                     }else if(key.isReadable()) {
                         read(key);
                     }
               }
         }

    }
}
```

My accept() and read() looks like this:

```
private void accept(SelectionKey key) {
   ServerSocketChannel server = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
   SocketChannel socketChannel = server.accept();
   socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
   socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
}

private void read(SelectionKey key) {
    SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    buffer.clear();
    int n = -1;

    n = channel.read(buffer);

    if(n == -1) {
        key.cancel();
        channel.close();
    }else{
      //read to buffer

    }
}
```

I have tried many ways but still cannot find out the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: This code doesn't compile. What is `selector()` in the `accept()` method? What's the real code?

Comment: @EJP Hi, the selector is a private field in this class.

Comment: Which never gets set, because of `Selector selector = Selector.open()` in the run method, which shadows it. So you should be getting an NPE in the `accept()` method when you use it. Or else this isn't the real code.

Comment: @EJP hi, it is just psudo code in the selector.open(), I have changed it according to the real code .